# Checking if a ring is Artinian.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, artinian

I am reviewing some commutative algebra notes for an upcoming course, and I found an exercise I wanted to solve, but I found out I absolutely have no idea how.

> Let $K$ be a field (I think $\operatorname{char}K\neq 2$, but the exercise doesn't outright state it), find whether $$R = k[x,y]/(2x^2 + 3y^2 - 11, x^2 - y^2 - 3)$$ and $$S = k[x,y]/(x^2 - xy + x, xy - y^2 + y)$$ are artinian or not.

I mean, they are of course noetherian, should I check if its Krull dimension is $0$, but I don't know how to check it. Could someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know some properties of Artinian rings? Try looking up some results on quotients.

Comment: I tried to run some computations. It seems like in the ideal quotient in the $R$ case, if we call $f, g$ the two polynomials, by doing$f + 3g$ we get $x^2 - 4 = 0$ and by doing $f - 2g$ we get $y^2 - 1 = 0$, so the terms in $x^2$ and $y^2$ can be computed as linear combinations of one degree terms. So it's a $k-$vector field with base $(1,x,y)$. Does this mean that it is immediately artinian? Because the DCC holds, so it is artinian as a module over itself, so it is artinian as a ring? I know some properties about quotients but not one that could help with the second one... Any clues?

Comment: Could $S$ be a similar case by computing $x^2$ and $y^2$ in terms of constants, $x,y,xy$?

Comment: Possibly a useful fact: for an algebra over a field $k$, being artinian is the same as being finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: Ok, so for example for $R$, that is an algebra over $k$, and is a finite-dimensional $k-$ vector space with basis $(1,x,y)$ since we can express $x^2=4$ and $y^2=1$?

Comment: Just realized I misspoke - I should have said for a finitely-generated algebra over $k$. (For example $k(x)$ is a field, hence artinian, but not a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space.)

Comment: A minor thing to point out: for the first case, you'll want $\operatorname{char} K \neq 5$, and this is the only characteristic restriction since $\det\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix} = -5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the meaning for Krull dimension of a ring $A$ equal to $0$ is that *every prime ideal in $A$ is also maximal.*

Here as you have realized, $$R=k[x,y]/(2x^2+3y^2-11,x^2-y^2-3)=k[x,y]/(x^2-4,y^2-1).$$

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $R$.

> Recall that a prime (resp. maximal) ideal in the quotient ring $A/I$ are precisely of the form $P/I$, where $P$ is a prime (resp. maximal) ideal of $A$ containing $I$.

Therefore, $$\mathfrak{p}=P/(x^2-4,y^2-1),$$ where $P$ is a prime ideal of $k[x,y]$ containing $(x^2-4,y^2-1)$.
Here we have trivial factorizations $$x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)\quad\text{and}\quad y^2-1=(y-1)(y+1).$$
Because $P$ is prime, at least one of $x-2$ and $x+2$ is in $P$, and similarly, at least one of $y-1$ and $y+1$ belongs to $P$.

> Every ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ of the form $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ for $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in k$ is maximal.

By displaying all cases, you shall see that $P$ is indeed a maximal ideal in $k[x,y]$, hence $\mathfrak{p}=P/(x^2-4,y^2-1)$ is also a maximal ideal in $R$, as desired.

---

Similarly, for $S$, observe that $$x^2-xy+x=x(x-y+1)\quad\text{and}\quad xy-y^2+y=y(x-y+1).$$
If $P$ is a prime ideal in $k[x,y]$ containing $(x^2-xy+x,xy-y^2+y)$, at least one of $x$ and $x-y+1$, and also at least one of $y$ and $x-y+1$, lies in $P$. However, there is one case that $$P=(x-y+1),$$ which is not maximal because $P\subsetneq(x,y-1)$ where $(x,y-1)$ is maximal in $k[x,y]$. Therefore, $S$ is not Artinian.

Comment: Thanks A LOT, you made my day. Everything is clear. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @WittyCatchphrase You are welcome! Glad to help!